# Sharding a Materialized View

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, optimization, materialized-view

I am a Postgres 15.3 AWS RDS instance and have a database that centers around one table, called `posts` that has 20 other relations to build the full object. The full query is about a second altogether and there are indexes on all the join keys. So in order to make reads fast we have a materialized view, `mv_posts` that represents the full table with ~20 joins and subselects and everything the front end needs (see below).

Here is the math that scares me, I have about 5000 rows and building the materialized view takes 2050 ms. This is not scalable. I am considering the following implementation.

Create a new materialized view `mv_new_posts` that keeps new posts created that day, and join it 1-1 to the `mv_posts` materialized view in a normal view and use that to query the posts object. I would then have to truncate `mv_new_posts` and regenerate `mv_posts` at midnight every night. This feels ugly but would scale for everything except when a `posts` row is updated, which would require regenerating the base view in some form.

I have considered the following other solutions:

- Partition Tables: The issue is that I dont have the row volume for this. I have not benchmarked it but do not beleive that with my small number of rows it would work.
- `[pg_ivm][1]` but the restrictions on outer (i.e. left) joins and aggregation functions make this impossible.
- Rolling my own, i.e. creating a table and triggers so that a single insert/update on a dependent table results in a single row update in the denormalized table that would replace the materialized view. This I have done on a smaller scale but do not feel would be worth the work here. In particular it would be a maintenance nightmare.

The materialized view definition is below, in case there is an obvious optimization I have missed.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_posts AS(
SELECT
    p.*,
    (
        setweight(to_tsvector('english', COALESCE(p.title, '')), 'A') ||
        setweight(to_tsvector('english', COALESCE(p.description, '')), 'B') ||
        setweight(to_tsvector('english', COALESCE(pc.email, '')), 'A') ||
        setweight(to_tsvector('english', COALESCE(d.name, '')), 'B')
    ) AS search_document,
    CASE WHEN pt.slug = 'ping' THEN True ELSE False END AS ping,
    ARRAY_REMOVE(vis.all_user_ids, NULL) AS all_visibility_user_ids,
    ARRAY_REMOVE(vis.user_ids, NULL) AS visibility_user_ids,
    ARRAY_REMOVE(vis.group_ids, NULL) AS visibility_group_ids,
    ARRAY_REMOVE(vis.org_ids, NULL) AS visibility_org_ids,
    CASE WHEN hm.id IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE ROW_TO_JSON(hm.*) END AS headline_file,
    COALESCE(JSON_AGG(DISTINCT JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
            'id', pm.id,
            'file_name', pm.file_name,
            'content_type', pm.content_type,
            'name', pm.name,
            'orphan', pm.orphan,
            'folder', pm.folder,
            'extension', pm.extension,
            'ordinal', pmj.ordinal)::JSONB
        ) FILTER (
            WHERE NOT (pm.id::TEXT = 'null') ), '[]'::JSON
        ) AS file,
    COALESCE(JSON_AGG(DISTINCT pmj.file_id) FILTER ( WHERE NOT (pmj.file_id IS NULL) ), '[]'::JSON) AS file_ids,
    COALESCE(JSON_AGG(DISTINCT pu) FILTER ( WHERE NOT (pu.id::TEXT = 'null') ), '[]'::JSON) AS users,
    COALESCE(JSON_AGG(DISTINCT pu.email) FILTER ( WHERE NOT (pu.id::TEXT = 'null') ), '[]'::JSON) AS user_emails,
    pt.id AS post_type_id,
    row_to_json(pt.*) AS post_type,
    row_to_json(pit.*) AS incident_type,
    row_to_json(pc.*) AS creator,
    d.id AS org_id,
    JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
        'id', d.id,
        'name', d.name,
        'admin_id', d.admin_id,'group_id', d.group_id,
        'creator_id', d.creator_id,
        'law_enforcement_partner', d.law_enforcement_partner,
        'slug', d.slug,
        'state', d.state,
        'location', JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
                'id', dl.id,
                'address', dl.address,
                'city', dl.city,
                'state_province', dl.state_province,
                'postal_code', dl.postal_code,
                'geojson', ST_AsGeoJSON(dl.geom)::JSON
            )
        ) AS org,
    ARRAY_REMOVE(ARRAY_AGG(pp.user_id),NULL) AS users_saved,
    COALESCE(
        JSON_AGG(
        DISTINCT
            JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
                'id', v.id,
                'make', v.make,
                'year', v.year,
                'state', v.state,
                'model', v.model,
                'color', v.color,
                'license_plate', v.license_plate,
                'vin', v.vin,
                'description', v.description,
                'file', (
                            SELECT COALESCE(JSON_AGG(vm.*) FILTER ( WHERE NOT (vm.id::TEXT = 'null') ), '[]'::JSON)
                            FROM file vm
                            JOIN car_file_join vmj ON vmj.file_id = vm.id
                            WHERE vmj.car_id=v.id
                )
            )::JSONB
        ) FILTER ( WHERE NOT (v.id::TEXT = 'null') ), '[]'::JSON)
        AS cars,COALESCE(
        JSON_AGG(
        DISTINCT
            JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
                'id', psn.id,
                'first_name', psn.first_name,
                'last_name', psn.last_name,
                'aliases', psn.aliases,
                'description', psn.description,
                'hair', psn.hair,
                'build', psn.build,
                'sex_id', psn.sex_id,
                'age', psn.age,
                'eye_color', psn.eye_color,
                'height', psn.height,
                'weight', psn.weight,
                'race', psn.race,
                'identifying_characteristics', psn.identifying_characteristics,
                'country', psn.country,
                'guy_type', row_to_json(psnt.*),
                'location', row_to_json(psnl.*),
                'file', (
                            SELECT COALESCE(JSON_AGG(psnm.*) FILTER ( WHERE NOT (psnm.id::TEXT = 'null') ), '[]'::JSON)
                            FROM file psnm
                            JOIN guy_file_join psnmj ON psnmj.file_id = psnm.id
                            WHERE psnmj.guy_id=psn.id
                )
            )::JSONB
        ) FILTER ( WHERE NOT (psn.id::TEXT = 'null') ), '[]'::JSON)
        AS guys,COALESCE(
        JSON_AGG(
        DISTINCT
            JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
                'id', l.id,
                'address', l.address,
                'city', l.city,
                'state_province', l.state_province,
                'postal_code', l.postal_code,
                'geojson', ST_AsGeoJSON(l.geom)::JSON,
                'location_string', l.location_string
            )::JSONB
        ) FILTER ( WHERE NOT (l.id::TEXT = 'null') ), '[]'::JSON) AS locations,
        COALESCE(
            ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT l.location_string) FILTER ( WHERE l.location_string IS NOT NULL ),
            '{}'::TEXT[]
        )AS location_strings,
    ST_UNION( l.geom )::geography  AS geom
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN visibility vis ON vis.post_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN file hm ON hm.id = p.headline_file_id
LEFT JOIN post_file_join pmj ON pmj.post_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN file pm ON pm.id=pmj.file_id
LEFT JOIN auth_users AS pc ON p.creator_id=pc.id
LEFT JOIN post_user_join puj ON puj.post_id=p.id
LEFT JOIN auth_users pu ON pu.id=puj.user_id
LEFT JOIN types pt ON pt.id=p.type_id
LEFT JOIN incident_types pit ON pit.id = p.incident_type_id
LEFT JOIN post_location_join plj ON plj.post_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN locations l ON plj.location_id = l.id
LEFT JOIN post_guy_join ppj ON ppj.post_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN guys psn ON psn.id = ppj.guy_id
LEFT JOIN guy_types psnt ON psnt.id = ppj.guy_type_id
LEFT JOIN locations psnl ON psnl.id= psn.current_location_id
LEFT JOIN post_car_join pvj ON pvj.post_id=p.id
LEFT JOIN cars v ON v.id = pvj.car_id
LEFT JOIN pinned_posts pp ON pp.post_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN orgs d ON pc.org_id = d.id
LEFT JOIN locations dl ON d.primary_location_id = dl.id
WHERE p.active
GROUP BY
    p.id,
    vis.all_user_ids,
    vis.user_ids,
    vis.org_ids,
    vis.group_ids,
    hm.id,
    pc.id,
    pt.id,
    pit.id,
    d.id,
    dl.id);
```

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: If you always query all your data, that will be slow. If you query just a few rows from your 20 tables, that should be very fast. Only join those tables that you actually need for a certain result. Don't fall into the trap of building a "world view" that joins all your tables.

Comment: 2050 ms for 5000 rows seems excessive. Should be much faster. I would first try to optimize the query. Investigate where the lion share is wasted. The odd mix of `json` and `jsonb` (converting back and forth) strikes me as a first suspect.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, Partitioning is not meant to be a performance improvement feature, it's meant to be a data management improvement feature.

Your code is just too complex in one place. At the end of the day you need to find a way to simplify the code while still meeting your objectives and if you can also do so in a way to leverage pg_ivm that would be ideal.

You may benefit from breaking your current materialized view down into multiple materialized views, so that they can individually be refreshed more efficiently and concurrently.

Doing so may even allow you to switch to `INNER JOIN`s instead, for the groups of related tables, when creating each materialized view. Not only will this be more efficient for the engine to generate a query plan for and result in a smaller set of data, it will also result in your data manipulations running against only the rows that matter, and then materializing those results. Then you can outer join to each of those materialized views with the main table to get all the rows back.

Following this design strategy will also make your code more manageable, and you can individually look at how to re-write your data manipulation logic of each materialized view to try to make it applicable for pg_ivm.